# Calculate the radius of convergence of the power series below.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

> (a) $\sum_{n = 0}^{{\infty}} x^{n!}$

> (b) $\sum_{n = 1}^{{\infty}} n^{-\sqrt n} x^n$

My attempt

(a) $\sum_{n = 0}^{{\infty}} x^{n!} \to r = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{a_n+1}= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^{n!}}{x^{(n+1)!}} =\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{x^{n!}}{x^{(n+1)n!}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{x^{n}x^1} $

(b)

$\sum_{n = 1}^{{\infty}} n^{- \sqrt n} x^n = \sum_{n = 1}^{{\infty}} \frac{1}{n^{\sqrt n}} x^n$

we apply the root test

$\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n^{\sqrt n}}} = \frac{1}{n^\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}$ now we have that $lim \frac{1}{n^\frac{1}{\sqrt n}} = 1$ if $n \ne 0$

$\lim \ln\frac{1}{n^\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}= \lim\ln\sqrt n \frac{1}{n} = 0$

Therefore

$\lim\frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}} = 0$

Not sure if I'm on the right track here.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your last step on (a) is wrong. It should be $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^{n\cdot n!}}$$

Comment: Please don't post two distinct questions as if it was a single one.

Comment: (a) Define $a_n=n$ if $n=m!$ for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, and $a_n=0$ otherwise. Then $\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=1=a$. The radius of convergence of the series is $1/a=1$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: what's wrong with posting two simple questions in a posting?

Comment: (b) you already got this part: (b) $\Big(\frac{1}{n^{\sqrt{n}}}\Big)^{1/n}=\frac{1}{n^{\sqrt{n}}}=e^{-\sqrt{n}\log n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$. This means that  the radius of convergence is $1/0=\infty$, in other words, th series converges for all $x$

Comment: @OliverDiaz What if (as it is the case here) one of the questions is a duplicate and the other one is not?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Then you pint that out with a link and end of story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you apply the ratio / root tests... we require

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac {a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|< 1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt [n] {a_n}< 1$

However, I think a comparson test is easier for a)

That is $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges if $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converges and there exists an $N>0$ such that $n>N \implies a_n \le b_n$ and diverges if $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ diverges and there exists an $N>0$ such that $n>N \implies a_n \ge b_n$

Compare to $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} x^n.$

The radius of convergence is $|x|<1$  inside this radius $x^n> x^{n!}$ and outisde this radius $x^n < x^{n!}$

Comment: Not of that is required. However, what Hadamard's criteria says is that of $\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}<1$ the series $\sum_na_n$ converges absolutely, while if $\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}>1$, the series diverges.